# Sending data from react native to ReactActivity and closing fragment

Tags: android, react-native, fragment

I am new to Native Module Linking. I am working on a react native project. When the app starts I have a created a functional component of react native which has button in it. When you press the button from react native side I have to open an react activity. For that I am using this function call from react native side **NativeModules.ManagerClass.showYourActivity**. For that I have created a class in native android extending ReactContextBaseJavaModule.

```
public class Manager extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    public Manager(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ManagerClass";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void showYourActivity() {
        ReactApplicationContext context = getReactApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class); // mContext got from 
        getCurrentActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }  

}
```

This opens up an android native activity.

```
public class MyActivity extends ReactActivity  {
   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
    }

    

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    
}
```

Now at a certain condition I have to open a fragment from this. Once this fragment is opened there is a button on fragment. On button click this fragment will send an event from android to react native and will fetch the data from api(This api has been called in react native function). To send the event I am using **NativeEventEmitter** and it works fine and I receive an event inside. To send the event from android to react native I using this :

```
reactInstanceManager.addReactInstanceEventListener(new ReactInstanceManager.ReactInstanceEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext context) {
                        context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                                .emit("onSessionConnect", "");
                        reactInstanceManager.removeReactInstanceEventListener(this);
                    }
                });
```

Now I have to send data back to activity which is retrieved from the api on react native function and have to close the fragment. My question is how can I do that I send data back to activity and close the fragment?. I have been now struggling to manage it for few days. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why u are using a native fragment for call an api. instead of make it in RN ?

Comment: So you mean to show fragment on activity I can also create a fragment on react native side?.

Comment: I have to show fragment on the current activity. How can I make it in RN?

Comment: I am making native fragment because I dont close the current activity. After pressing the button from fragment activity continues. It is actually a application for taxi drivers. So when taxi driver reaches a destination we have to open a fragment that you are at the destination and then call api. Then you move to next point continuing the activity.

Comment: My questions is you have an existing native app and you add RN to this project or you have a RN project and you add fragments to this RN project instead of use RN to make you what you want.

Comment: I have a RN project and I am adding fragments to RN project

Comment: k so why you want to add native fragments instead of make a modal in RN and call there your api ?. I just asking this because I work alot with native modules and it can be a pain, so if you can avoid its better :D

Comment: Actually I am using mapbox maps api which is not supported on react native so therefore I have to jump from react native to android native.

Comment: k so you add the listener in react layer ?. I think when you hit the listener you can call another bridge method that close your fragment.

Comment: Yes I have added listener in the react layer. By another bridge method you mean "@ReactMethod"?

Comment: yep you can pass there the data and get the fragment instance and close it

Comment: Yes okay thank you. I am passing the data to @ReactMethod and then using the interface to pass it to the ReactActivity where I am closing the fragment.